# What is the locus of $\vec r$ if $(\vec a - \vec b)\cdot\vec r=\frac {1}{2}({\vert\vec a\vert}^2-{\vert\vec b\vert}^2)$?

Tags: vectors

**Question.** I want to find out the locus of point whose position vector is $\vec r$, in *three-dimensional* space. Vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are two fixed position vectors. The following relationship between the three vectors is satisfied.$$(\vec a - \vec b)\cdot\vec r=\frac {1}{2}({\vert\vec a\vert}^2-{\vert\vec b\vert}^2)$$

---

**My Attempt.** I tried to rearrange the relationship equation by "multiply out" the dot product and turning the moduli squared into dot products. Finally I got the following equation but still stuck.$$\vec a\cdot (2\vec r - \vec a)=\vec b\cdot(2\vec r - \vec b)$$

---

**Comment.** Please do not tell me the answer directly. What I need is some hint with which I could make further progress on my own. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: Depending on what a and b are, you will likely get many solutions (infinitely many? figure this part out), to see what happens depending on the components of a and b, write a and b in terms of their components and expand out the left side, the right side is just some real number.

Comment: What is $(a-b)\cdot(a+b)$ ?

Comment: @Countable Thanks a lot. Your hint helped me figure that the equation describes a plane. Hmm, but I don't think the solutions depend on vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ since they are constant. Anyhow, I got it. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: $$\vec{n}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)=0$$

is the equation of a plane in $3$D, that passes through the point $\vec{r}_0$ with normal vector $\vec{n}$.

Comment: With your two hints (one as a comment), I completely got it. I knew this plane equation but I did not remind myself while doing that question, indicating that I need much more practice! Anyway, thanks a lot! I am giving you a green check.